# Carrusel con slick en Hubspot errores

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy tratando de implementar un carrusel Slick en mi proyecto de HubSpot, pero estoy experimentando algunos problemas con el CSS. He configurado el carrusel utilizando un módulo HTML en HubSpot, y estoy tratando de ajustar el CSS para controlar el espaciado entre las tarjetas y hacer las transiciones más suaves.

Aquí está mi estructura de código:

Un módulo HTML donde se inicializa el carrusel Slick utilizando jQuery.
Un módulo CSS donde estoy tratando de ajustar el estilo del carrusel.
El problema principal que enfrento es que las tarjetas del carrusel están demasiado juntas y las transiciones son bruscas. He intentado ajustar los márgenes y las transiciones en el CSS, pero no estoy obteniendo los resultados deseados.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme a identificar qué estoy haciendo mal en mi código CSS? ¿Hay alguna configuración específica que deba cambiar en el CSS o en la inicialización del carrusel Slick para resolver estos problemas?

Agradezco cualquier ayuda o consejo que puedan brindarme. ¡Gracias!

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

    Este es mi module.js aca incorpore el Slick peor no funciona correctamente.

              $(document).ready(function () {
                    const carousels = $(".bzb-wrap-1");
                
                    carousels.each(function () {
                        const carousel = $(this);
                        const carouselWrapper = carousel.find(".bzb-wrap-2");
                        const carouselItems = carouselWrapper.find(".bzb-wrap-square-1");
                        const totalItems = carouselItems.length;
                
                        carouselWrapper.slick({
                            centerMode: true,
                            centerPadding: '60px',
                            slidesToShow: 3,
                            focusOnSelect: true,
                            speed: 400,
                            responsive: [
                                {
                                    breakpoint: 768,
                                    settings: {
                                        arrows: false,
                                        centerMode: true,
                                        centerPadding: '40px',
                                        slidesToShow: 1
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    breakpoint: 480,
                                    settings: {
                                        arrows: false,
                                        centerMode: true,
                                        centerPadding: '40px',
                                        slidesToShow: 1
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            accessibility: true
                        });
                
                        // Función para actualizar la clase activa después de cambiar de diapositiva
                        function setActiveItem() {
                            carouselItems.removeClass("active").find('.bzb-text-1, .bzb-text-2').removeClass('active');
                            const centerIndex = carouselWrapper.slick('slickCurrentSlide');
                            carouselItems.eq(centerIndex).addClass("active").find('.bzb-text-1, .bzb-text-2').addClass('active');
                        }
                
                        // Evento para activar el elemento central después del cambio de diapositiva
                        carouselWrapper.on('afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide) {
                            setActiveItem();
                        });
                    
                        // Evento para agregar clase de transición a los elementos no activos antes de cambiar de diapositiva
                        carouselWrapper.on('beforeChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
                            carouselItems.removeClass("active");
                            carouselItems.eq(nextSlide).addClass("active-transition");
                        });
                
                        // Evento para limpiar la clase de transición después del cambio de diapositiva
                        carouselWrapper.on('setPosition', function () {
                            carouselItems.removeClass("active-transition");
                            setActiveItem();
                        });
                    });
                });
```

introducir el código aquí

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->

   Esta es mi module css , donde tengo dificultadas, quiero cambiar muchas cosas del css.

            
                .bzb-wrap-square-1 {
                    width: 400px !important; /* Ancho de las tarjetas */
                    height: 420px !important; /* Altura de las tarjetas */
                }
                
                .bzb-wrap-2 .slick-slide {
                    margin-left: 20px !important;
                    margin-right: 20px !important; /* Ajusta el espacio entre las tarjetas */
                    transform: scale(0.8); /* Reducir el tamaño de las tarjetas inactivas */
                    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out; /* Agregar transición para suavizar el cambio de tamaño */
                    z-index: 0; /* Asegurar que las tarjetas inactivas estén detrás del elemento activo */
                }
                
                .bzb-wrap-square-1 {
                    transform: scale(1);
                    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
                    transition: all .3s ease-out;
                    z-index: 1;
                }
                
                .bzb-wrap-square-1.active {
                    transform: scale(1.1); /* Ajustar el tamaño del elemento activo */
                    z-index: 1; /* Asegurar que el elemento activo esté adelante */
                    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Agregar una sombra para un efecto 3D */
                }
                .bzb-wrap-square-1:not(.active) {
                    transform: scale(0.8);
                }
                
                .bzb-wrap-square-1.active + .bzb-wrap-square-1.active {
                    margin-left: 30px !important; /* Espacio entre tarjetas */
                  margin-right: 30px !important;
                }
```

introducir el código aquí

```
              <!-- language: lang-html -->
```

este es mi module.HTML, aca nose si me gustaria cambiar algo .

```
                <div class="bzb-section-1 {{module.style.Margins}} ">
                      <div class="bzb-container-1">
                
                        <div class="bzb-wrap-1 ">
                          <div class="bzb-square-1 ">
                       <div class="bzb-arrow-wrap-left bzb-arrow-wrap-left-1">
                              <a href="#" class="bzb-link-arrow w-inline-block"
                                >
                              
                              <!-- STARTS Left arrow icon -->   
                                
                                
                               {% if module.arrow_left.src %}
                    {% set sizeAttrs = 'width="{{ module.arrow_left.width|escape_attr }}" height="{{ module.arrow_left.height|escape_attr }}"' %}
                    {% if module.arrow_left.size_type == 'auto' %}
                        {% set sizeAttrs = 'width="{{ module.arrow_left.width|escape_attr }}" height="{{ module.arrow_left.height|escape_attr }}" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;"' %}
                    {% elif module.arrow_left.size_type == 'auto_custom_max' %}
                        {% set sizeAttrs = 'width="{{ module.arrow_left.max_width|escape_attr }}" height="{{ module.arrow_left.max_height|escape_attr }}" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;"' %}
                    {% endif %}
                     {% set loadingAttr = module.arrow_left.loading != 'disabled' ? 'loading="{{ module.arrow_left.loading|escape_attr }}"' : '' %}
                    <img class="bzb-arrow-1" src="{{ module.arrow_left.src|escape_url }}" alt="{{ module.arrow_left.alt|escape_attr }}" {{ loadingAttr }} {{ sizeAttrs }}>
                {% endif %} 
                              
                          </a>
                            </div>
                            
                            <!-- ENDS Left arrow icon -->   
                
                            
                            
                            <!-- STARTS icons cards -->
                            
                            <div class="bzb-wrap-2 slick-carousel">
                          
                              
                              {% for item in module.icon_cards %}
                    
                <div class="bzb-wrap-square-1 ">
                                <div class="bzb-wrap-pic">
                                  {% if item.icon.src %}
                        {% set sizeAttrs = 'width="{{ item.icon.width|escape_attr }}" height="{{ item.icon.height|escape_attr }}"' %}
                        {% if item.icon.size_type == 'auto' %}
                            {% set sizeAttrs = 'width="{{ item.icon.width|escape_attr }}" height="{{ item.icon.height|escape_attr }}" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;"' %}
                        {% elif item.icon.size_type == 'auto_custom_max' %}
                            {% set sizeAttrs = 'width="{{ item.icon.max_width|escape_attr }}" height="{{ item.icon.max_height|escape_attr }}" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;"' %}
                        {% endif %}
                         {% set loadingAttr = item.icon.loading != 'disabled' ? 'loading="{{ item.icon.loading|escape_attr }}"' : '' %}
                        <img  class="bzb-pic-square" src="{{ item.icon.src|escape_url }}" alt="{{ item.icon.alt|escape_attr }}" {{ loadingAttr }} {{ sizeAttrs }}>
                    {% endif %}
                                </div>
                                <div class="bzb-square-text">
                                  <div class="bzb-text-1">{% inline_text field="text" value="{{ item.text }}" %}</div>
                                  <div class="bzb-text-2">
                                    {% inline_text field="paragraph" value="{{ item.paragraph }}" %}
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                
                
                
                {% endfor %}
                              
                              
                
                            
                            
                          </div>
                            
                            
                            
                         <!-- ENDS icons cards -->   
                            
                            
                            
                          <div class="bzb-arrow-wrap-right bzb-arrow-wrap-right-1">
                              
                            
                              
                             <!-- STARTs Right arrow icon -->   
                  
                              
                              <a href="#" class="bzb-link-arrow-1 w-inline-block"
                                >
                                
                                {% if module.arrow_right.src %}
                    {% set sizeAttrs = 'width="{{ module.arrow_right.width|escape_attr }}" height="{{ module.arrow_right.height|escape_attr }}"' %}
                    {% if module.arrow_right.size_type == 'auto' %}
                        {% set sizeAttrs = 'width="{{ module.arrow_right.width|escape_attr }}" height="{{ module.arrow_right.height|escape_attr }}" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;"' %}
                    {% elif module.arrow_right.size_type == 'auto_custom_max' %}
                        {% set sizeAttrs = 'width="{{ module.arrow_right.max_width|escape_attr }}" height="{{ module.arrow_right.max_height|escape_attr }}" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;"' %}
                    {% endif %}
                     {% set loadingAttr = module.arrow_right.loading != 'disabled' ? 'loading="{{ module.arrow_right.loading|escape_attr }}"' : '' %}
                    <img  class="bzb-arrow-2" src="{{ module.arrow_right.src|escape_url }}" alt="{{ module.arrow_right.alt|escape_attr }}" {{ loadingAttr }} {{ sizeAttrs }}>
                {% endif %}
                                
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            
                            
                            <!-- ENDS Right arrow icon -->
                            
                            
                        </div>
                      </div>
                        
                        <!-- Segundo carrusel -->
                <div class="bzb-section-1 {{module.style.Margins}} ">
                    <div class="bzb-container-1">
                        <div class="bzb-wrap-1">
                            <div class="bzb-square-1">
                                <div class="bzb-arrow-wrap-left bzb-arrow-wrap-left-1">
                                   
                             
                              
                              <!-- STARTs Left arrow icon -->
                              
                              <a href="#" class="bzb-link-arrow w-inline-block"
                                >
                              
                               {% if module.arrow_left.src %}
                    {% set sizeAttrs = 'width="{{ module.arrow_left.width|escape_attr }}" height="{{ module.arrow_left.height|escape_attr }}"' %}
                    {% if module.arrow_left.size_type == 'auto' %}
                        {% set sizeAttrs = 'width="{{ module.arrow_left.width|escape_attr }}" height="{{ module.arrow_left.height|escape_attr }}" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;"' %}
                    {% elif module.arrow_left.size_type == 'auto_custom_max' %}
                        {% set sizeAttrs = 'width="{{ module.arrow_left.max_width|escape_attr }}" height="{{ module.arrow_left.max_height|escape_attr }}" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;"' %}
                    {% endif %}
                     {% set loadingAttr = module.arrow_left.loading != 'disabled' ? 'loading="{{ module.arrow_left.loading|escape_attr }}"' : '' %}
                    <img class="bzb-arrow-1" src="{{ module.arrow_left.src|escape_url }}" alt="{{ module.arrow_left.alt|escape_attr }}" {{ loadingAttr }} {{ sizeAttrs }}>
                {% endif %} 
                              
                              
                              </a>
                              
                              
                             <!-- ENDS Left arrow icon --> 
                              
                              
                            </div>
                             <div class="bzb-wrap-2 ">
                              
                              
                             <!-- START Picture Cards Group -->
                              
                              {% for item in module.field_group %}
                              
                              <div class="bzb-wrap-square-1">
                                <div class="bzb-picwrap-1">
                                  <div class="bzb-picwrap-2">
                                    {% if item.icon.src %}
                        {% set sizeAttrs = 'width="{{ item.icon.width|escape_attr }}" height="{{ item.icon.height|escape_attr }}"' %}
                        {% if item.icon.size_type == 'auto' %}
                            {% set sizeAttrs = 'width="{{ item.icon.width|escape_attr }}" height="{{ item.icon.height|escape_attr }}" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;"' %}
                        {% elif item.icon.size_type == 'auto_custom_max' %}
                            {% set sizeAttrs = 'width="{{ item.icon.max_width|escape_attr }}" height="{{ item.icon.max_height|escape_attr }}" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;"' %}
                        {% endif %}
                         {% set loadingAttr = item.icon.loading != 'disabled' ? 'loading="{{ item.icon.loading|escape_attr }}"' : '' %}
                        <img class="bzb-pic-1" src="{{ item.icon.src|escape_url }}" alt="{{ item.icon.alt|escape_attr }}" {{ loadingAttr }} {{ sizeAttrs }}>
                    {% endif %}
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="bzb-square-text">
                                  <div class="bzb-text-1">{% inline_text field="text" value="{{ item.text }}" %}</div>
                                  <div class="bzb-text-2">
                                    {% inline_text field="paragraph" value="{{ item.paragraph }}" %}
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              
                             {% endfor %}
                             
                              <!-- ENDS Picture Cards Group -->
                              
                              
                            </div>
                         <div class="bzb-arrow-wrap-right bzb-arrow-wrap-right-1">
                              
                              
                            <!-- STARTs Right arrow icon -->  
                              
                              <a href="#" class="bzb-link-arrow-1 w-inline-block"
                                >
                                
                                
                                {% if module.arrow_right.src %}
                    {% set sizeAttrs = 'width="{{ module.arrow_right.width|escape_attr }}" height="{{ module.arrow_right.height|escape_attr }}"' %}
                    {% if module.arrow_right.size_type == 'auto' %}
                        {% set sizeAttrs = 'width="{{ module.arrow_right.width|escape_attr }}" height="{{ module.arrow_right.height|escape_attr }}" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;"' %}
                    {% elif module.arrow_right.size_type == 'auto_custom_max' %}
                        {% set sizeAttrs = 'width="{{ module.arrow_right.max_width|escape_attr }}" height="{{ module.arrow_right.max_height|escape_attr }}" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;"' %}
                    {% endif %}
                     {% set loadingAttr = module.arrow_right.loading != 'disabled' ? 'loading="{{ module.arrow_right.loading|escape_attr }}"' : '' %}
                    <img  class="bzb-arrow-2" src="{{ module.arrow_right.src|escape_url }}" alt="{{ module.arrow_right.alt|escape_attr }}" {{ loadingAttr }} {{ sizeAttrs }}>
                {% endif %}
                              
                              
                              </a>
                              
                           
                              
                              <!-- ENDS Right arrow icon -->
                              
                              
                              
                            
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                
                      </div>
                    </div>
```